# How to wrap c++ code calling python as .dll or .so?

Tags: python, c++, g++, python-embedding

I want to wrap my c++ code as .so and .dll file.I know how to wrap c++ code as dynamic library, But my c++ code is calling python, normally we call embedding python.
I write a basic simple code.
python code:

```
  def init_test(env, mode):
      print(env)
      print(mode)
      return 1
```

c++ code calling python:

```
#define PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN
#include <Python.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>

/**
 * @description: run risk performance use Python
 * @param {string} env
 * @param {string } mode
 * @return {*}
 */
extern "C" int init_python_test(char* env,  char* mode) {
    std::cout << "start" <<std::endl;
    if(Py_IsInitialized == 0){
        std::cout << "not init" << std::endl;
    }
    else{
        std::cout << "init already" <<std::endl;
        //std::cout << Py_FinalizeEx() <<std::endl;
        Py_Finalize();
    }
    std::cout << "init:"<<Py_IsInitialized() << std::endl;
    Py_Initialize();
    PyErr_Print();
    std::cout <<"second" <<std::endl;
    PyRun_SimpleString("import sys");
    PyRun_SimpleString("sys.path.append('./')");
    std::cout <<"ok" <<std::endl;

    //int res;
    PyObject *pModule,*pFunc = NULL;
    PyObject *pArgs, *pValue = NULL;
    pModule = PyImport_ImportModule("mini");//0x7ffff64b9cc0
    if(!pModule)
        std::cout << "can't open python file" << std::endl;
    PyErr_Print();
    pFunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, "init_test"); 
    PyErr_Print();

    if(pFunc && PyCallable_Check(pFunc)){
        
        PyErr_Print();
        
        pValue = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, Py_BuildValue("(ss)", env, mode));
        PyErr_Print();
    
    }
    Py_FinalizeEx();
    return 1;
}

int main(){
    char  *env = (char*)"prod";
    char * mode = (char*)"prod";
    init_python_test(env, mode);
    std::cout << "ok" <<std::endl;

}
```

I am able to run my c++ code properly with g++ command linked with python dynamic library. And I can use g++ to wrap my c++ code as .so file. When I use another c++ code and python code to test the init_python_test function. Segmentation fault occurs when the code runs into Py_Initialize().

So, how to resolve this question? and did I wrap c++ code properly with g++? here is my shell.

```
g++ -fPIC -shared -Wall -o libtest.so ./mini_test.cpp -DLINUX -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 -I /usr/include/python3.8 -L/usr/lib/python3 -L/usr/lib/python3.8 -lpython3.8
```

Somebody helps me! plz!!! thank u!!!!